# Calling from Xtend to Java with multi-dimensional array parameters

Tags: xtend

I need to call a Java method from Xtend that expects a two dimensional array such as:

> javafunc (String [][] {{"0","1"}.{"2","3"}})

My initial thought is to write a Java static method that accepts a List of arrays,
converts it to a two dimensional array and calls the underlying Java method. Before I do this I would like to know if there are better solutions. This one is a bit ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using arrays, you could use a list of pairs.

```
#["0" -> "1", "1" -> "2"]
```

I would convert it using a extension function instead of writing a wrapper for the java function. That way it is more resuable.

```
javafunc(#["0" -> "1", "1" -> "2"].toArrays)

def String[][] toArrays(Iterable<Pair<String,String>> pairs) {
    // convert pairs to 2d array ...
}
```

Whether this is a good solution depends a bit on what the data represents though, pairs can be confusing if there is no obvious relationship between key and value.